# вернуть список, отсортированный по количеству, а для одинакового количества, по артикулу, без учета регистра

Tags: java

Мне нужно  в методе, вернуть список объектов, отсортированных по параметру "количество"(available), если параметр "количество" одинаков для нескольких объектов списка, -  провести сортировку по параметру "артикул"(number), без учёта регистра.
Метод с уже проведённой сортировкой по параметру количество.

```
public List<Goods> sortByAvailabilityAndNumber() {
    List<Goods> result = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.available))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());//
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно воспользоваться методами построения компараторов для лексикографического сравнения для нескольких компараторов:

```
public List<Goods> sortByAvailabilityAndNumber() {
    List<Goods> result = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.available)
                  .thenComparing(e -> e.number.toLowerCase()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());//
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, даже не знал про thenComparing().